# difference between Button button = (Button) v; and Button button = (Button)findviewbyid(r.id.button1);

Tags: android, button, android-studio

Could somebody tell me what is the difference between

```
Button button = (Button)v
```

and

```
Button button = (Button)findviewbyid(R.id.button)
```

Comment: what is v in this case?

Comment: dont know thats why i asked i was going through a tutorial and in that tutorial the guys used button button = (button)v in an onclick method

Comment: The onClick method took a View object and he casted it to a button object for whatever reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is different assuming this code.

```
View v = findviewbyid(R.id.button);
Button button = (Button)v;
```

and

```
Button button = (Button)findviewbyid(R.id.button);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Button button = (Button)v

He is casting v in `Button`  (forcefull verify that click is form button 
) as `onOclick()` may be on `Button` or on `Im
ageButton`

> Button button = (Button)findviewbyid(R.id.button)

this is also same casting to `Button` but it's initialization

Answer (score 0):

```
Button button = (Button)v // casting v as a button
```

considering v is a view that you already have in your code this statement casts that view into Button and creates a reference variable named button.

```
Button button = (Button)findviewbyid(R.id.button)
```

this statement finds the view with the specific id form the xml that is attached to the activity then casts it to a Button and creates a reference variable named button